# Notification text in android is not shown completely

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio

I am new to push notifications in IBM mobile first Hybrid platform. I am able to send push notifications to all devices. However, in android devices I'm not able to see the complete message; only half of the message is shown. Please suggest answers.

Answer (score 1):

just change the character settings from medium to small

```
settings >  character > small
```

Comment: Thank u Alex, But this is device level  configuration. This will affect the total device's font. How can we achieve the same through any worklight APIs?